# Can you to take a healing surge in response to being bloodied that is not Second Wind?

Tags: dnd-4e, healing

My group has been using a rule ever since we started playing D&D 4e.  I did a search and can not find a reference to it anywhere. I need to know if I missed the reference to it or if we have accidentally made a house rule.

This is the Rule:
Whenever a character is bloodied for the first time in a combat encounter, that character may immediately take a healing surge as an interrupt in response. This has been applied equally to monsters too if they have healing surges.  A character can only do this once per encounter and only when they are bloodied for the first time.  They must also take a short rest between encounters to be able to use this.  This does not count against Second Wind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There is no such general rule.**

There may be a couple specific ways to gain this ability, but it isn't very common.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am concluding. We think as a group we may have very early on misread or misinterpreted the Second Wind and this came out of it.  We are going to drop this from our gaming.  It makes the characters too hard to fight.

Comment: @Ace, np - it happens.  My worst problem is still trying to use D&D3e rules in D&D4.  I have a hard time forgetting things, I still instinctively grab the dice to take an AOO against someone standing up from prone :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you be referring to the *Fighter 2* power:

> `Minor Resurgence`?<sup>[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12671)</sup>
>   Encounter Martial Minor Action Personal
>
> **Prerequisite:** You must have training in Endurance.
>   **Requirement:** You must be bloodied.
>   **Effect:** You gain 5/10/15 temporary hit points.

There is also the *Cleric Feature* that grants something like this ability:

> `Healer's Mercy`<sup>[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7885)</sup> Encounter Divine, Healing Standard Action Close burst 5
>
> **Target:** Each bloodied ally in the burst
>   **Effect:** Each target can spend a healing surge. You are weakened until the end of your next turn.

Comment: Neither of those are interrupts though.

Comment: Searching DDI with "interrupt bloodied healing" doesn't return anything that is useful. Dropping "interrupt" gets you closer.

Comment: Yeah, after another search, combined with what is shown here, I and the group have concluded that what we are using is an accidental house rule.  I have talked with he group and we will be dropping it from now on.